# Многомерный массив из строки в java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив вида

```
String[] arr = {
    "a (51)", 
    "b (13)",
    "c (55)"
    };
```

в котором нужно провести сортировку элементов по значениям в скобках. Думала разбить на два списка (name и value), сортировать value, сопоставляя списки и зашла в тупик, больше идей нет. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 3):

Такой способ Вам подходит?

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class ArraySort {
        private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<number>\\d+)");

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] arr = {
                    "a (51)",
                    "b (13)",
                    "c (55)"
            };

            Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return getValue(o1).compareTo(getValue(o2));
                }
            });
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        }

        private static String getValue(String value) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                return matcher.group("number");
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

[b (13), a (51), c (55)]

Answer (score 0):

Разбить на два массива - плохое решение. Лучше иметь один массив объектов, которые инкапсулируют в себе два поля - value и name

Comment: Указанный ответ лучше использовать как комментарий к вопросу. В ответе же лучше привести пример реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Можно отсортировать элементы массива по числам в скобках и собрать из них карту:

```java
String[] arr = {"a (51)", "b (13)", "c (55)"};

Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(arr)
        // из каждой строки выкидыаем скобки
        // и разделяем на массив подстрок по пробелу
        .map(str -> str.replaceAll("[\\(\\)]", "").split(" "))
        // сортировка чисел по возрастанию
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1])))
        // собираем в карту
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                a -> String.valueOf(a[0]),
                a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]),
                (e1, e2) -> e1 + e2,
                LinkedHashMap::new));


System.out.println(map); // {b=13, a=51, c=55}
```